# C - separating strings in the input stream

Tags: c, arrays, string, input, scanf

My program is supposed to be able to create new structures and store them in an array, however, the commands for storing and displaying pose difficulty.

- To create a new variable struct in the array, the user inputs "set varname varcontents
- To display the contents of a variable, the user inputs "set varname"
- To display all variables, the user inputs "set"

I can't quite figure out how to check if there are multiple strings ("set" "varname" "varcontents") or if there is only "set"

```
    char command[2][5] = { "set", "clear"};

    printf("prompt> ");
    scanf("%s",inputString);

    if(strncmp(inputString,command[0],5) == 0 )
    {   
        //code to create new struct, display structs etc...
    }
    else if(strncmp(inputString,command[1],5) == 0 )
    {
         //code to clear struct
    }
```

Right now the if loop only passes if the user inputs "set".
I could probably take the comparison of the first few letters, and then take the full comparison and subtract the first few characters to generate the name of the new struct, but this seems too complicated, there must be an easier solution.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: use `malloc()/calloc()` within the if block of required  type

Comment: Wouldn't this be much easier if you parsed the string first using something like `strtok`?

Comment: Provide more examples of your expected input.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the sentence into array of words and you can compare those words and run your functions.Give a try and If u want i can post the code.

Answer (score 0):

There are some Problems in your code. First of all, scanf won't read "set variablename variablevalue", because it skips on whitespaces. It's not considered safe anyway, since it allows buffer overflows easily - specially beginners should rather use [fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).
But the main Problem is somewhere else - Consider the following snippet:

```
scanf("%s", inputString);
```

What would happen if you enter: 'set xyz 12'? scanf would just read 'set' and the other Input will be ignored. So there's no point in checking against the other parameters 'xyz' and '12'.
Maybe you want to use something like

```
scanf("%s %s %s", inputString1, inputString2, inputString3);
```

but I would advise against it and rather use fgets(). Apart from that you just Need simple pointer arithmetic to skip over the characters which you already processed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (){
  char* command[] = { "set", "clear"};
  char input[256], varName[256], varContents[256];
  char* pointer = input;
  int i = 0;
  printf("prompt>");
   fgets(input, 255, stdin);
  if(strncmp(pointer, command[0], strlen(command[0])) == 0 ){
    pointer += strlen(command[0]) + 1;
    while(*pointer != ' ' && *pointer != '\n'){
      varName[i] = *pointer;
      pointer++;
      i++;
    }
    if(*pointer == '\n'){ printf("Not enough arguments"); return 1; }
    varName[i] = '\0';
    pointer++;
    i = 0;
    while(*pointer != ' ' && *pointer != '\n'){
      varContents[i] = *pointer;
      pointer++;
      i++;
    }
    varContents[i] = '\0';
    //code to create new struct, display structs etc...
    printf("Set VarName: %s VarContents: %s\n", varName, varContents);
  }else if(strncmp(pointer, command[1], strlen(command[1])) == 0 ){
    //code to clear struct
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only reading one string, you should use two scanf's to read two

```
char arg0[30], arg1[30];
while (scanf("%s %s", arg0, arg1) < 2);
```

That will read until both strings are entered.

Hope this helps.